# Этимология слова "курица"

Tags: этимология

Какое общепринятое происхождение слова "курица"?

По-видимому, название пришло вместе с самими курами — из Персии или Греции.

В Викисловаре невразумительно написано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *курица* образовано добавлением суффикса *-иц(а)* к основе *кур*. Предполагается, что эта основа существовало уже в праславянском языке, т. к. во многих славянских языках названия этой домашней птицы сходны: ср. польское и словенское *kura*.

В южнославянских языках, однако, встречаем болг. и макед. *кокошка* (вспомните междометие *ко-ко-ко*), что дает основание считать все  указанные выше названия (и русские *кур, кура* в том числе) **этимологически звукоподражательными**.

Answer (score 1):

**Кур** - это общеславянское слово, то есть не заимствовано, а есть почти во всех славянских языках:укр. *кур*, ст.-слав. *коуръ*, словен. *kùr*, чеш. *kour, kur*, слвц. *kúr*, польск. *kur*, в.-луж., н.-луж. *kur*. Родственно лтш. *kaurêt* «реветь, кричать», лат. *caurīre* «реветь (о пантере в пору течки)», др.-инд. *kāuti* «кричит, ревет».

Скорее всего слово образовано путём звукоподражания, ср. **кукареку**

Answer (score -3):

http://www.proza.ru/2016/02/28/1935  :
...
Изначальное основное значение слова-корня *К* близко (примерно соответствует) значениям слова Кон в древнеславянском - начало-КОНец, край, предел (граница), цикл; И (так же - примерно) слово-корень *Р* "=" Ра-Творец (солнце) - энергия, сила, информация (смыслы), Речь, передача смыслов (инфомации-энергии).

Естественно и логично, что последующие производные вариации от этих первоначальных смыслов (слов *Р* и *К*) - Правитель Власть Управление Речь Творение (действие) Контроль Ограничение Укрытие Покрытие Поток Судьба (Рок) Свет Луч Шип Скала Острие (зубец) и т. п.
  Звукоподражание животным, в процессе словообразования - с далёкого боку. 
Ворона удостоилась выдающегося внимания - именно благодаря своей исключительной способности изРеКать ключевые согласные фонемы. Возможно что и корова получила свой "священный статус" по той же ("ОМ") причине. Логично  - что ворона стала "КРоу" (англ.), много позднее, чем уже были-именовались: 
Солнце - "Ра", лучь - "Рэй" (англ.),
;  Ka (санскрит) - ПРАВИТЕЛЬ, солнце, звук, свет, огонь, ... 
;;  Kara - Ограничение; солнечный луч; повелитель, мастер, автор, деятель, 
производитель, в результате чего; изготовление, акт; рука; дело; помощь, содействие.
;;;  RAka - Солнце, колчан, богатство.
;;  KhaRa - пучок лучей, сноп лучей в солнечной короне, обжигающий, имеющий острые края, острый, кислый, вредный, жёсткий, тернистое растение.

И ведь очевидно, что новейшее слово "Укр" (особенно актуальное в сочетании "Древний Укр") - это не просто вульгаризм; Но лингво-законный отклик вселенского Логоса на реальный исторический и физичный факт - появление Властелина вселенной - превосходнейшей (во ВСЕХ отношениях) Сущности (эгрегора - правителя).
Наивно полагать - что "Укр" это сокращение от "Украинец". Так же ошибочно считать что Король - от рачка Криль (пурпурная краска, хитон монарха ... и прочие проекции). 
Слова рождаются из звуков-смыслов, и УКР = К-Р = Кон Ра = Закон Солнца = Божественный Свет-Сила.
Не случайно на древнейшем языке - тамильском - ;;;;  Kuru - Божество (Юпитер), правитель.
И в гальском Кир - Князь.
А в древнеславянском Кур - петух; А петух во множестве культур - это символ власти-силы.
Укр Король Кур и Рекс = Властелин-Повелитель-Сила !
УКР = К-Р = Р-К = ;;;  RAka (санскрит) - Солнце !

Вики:
Укор.
Из у- + -кор- (корить), далее от праслав. *korъ; *kor;;t;, от кот. в числе прочего 
произошли: ст.-слав. ;коръ (др.-греч. ;;;;;), церк.-слав. коръ, русск. корить, укор, укр. коріти, болг. кор, сюда же русск. покорить, перекор, болг. коря; «порицаю», сербохорв. ко;рити, ко;ри;м «укорять», словенск. kor;ti «наказывать», чешск. ko;it «смирять, преклонять голову перед к.-л.», словацк. kоri;, польск. korzy; «унижать, смирять», в.-луж. po-kori;; другая ступень чередования: кара;ть, ка;ра. 
Восходит к праиндоевр. *kar. Родственно латышск. karin;t «дразнить, раздражать», 
вост.-лит. k;rinti — то же, греч. ;;;;; ; ;;;;;. ;;;;;;;;;; ; ;;;;;;;;;; (Гесихий), лат. carin;re «поносить, высмеивать», др.-ирл. c;aire «упрек». 
Не связано, по-видимому, с лит. k;rias «войско», k;ras «война», др.-перс. k;ra- 
«войско, народ», ирл. cuire «войско», готск. harjis, др.-в.-нем. heri — то же, греч. 
;;;;;;;; «военачальник, повелитель». 
Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера;...
...