# Почему во мн. ч. отброшен суффикс: "курица гриль", но "куры гриль"?

Tags: этимология, единственное-множественное-число, суффиксы

Почему для слова *курица*, при его употреблении во множественном числе (н-р, курам на смех), происходит отбрасывание уменьшительно-ласкательного суффикса *-ица*?

Comment: По-моему, вопрос надо ставить по-другому: почему в одних сутациях говорят "куры", а в других — "курицы"?

Comment: Полезная информация: [Этимология слова “курица”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441195/%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Функция этого суффикса здесь вряд ли "уменьшительно-ласкательная"; по-видимому (если вспомнить поговорку "как **кур** во щи") она заключается в образовании сущ. женского рода от "кур" (устар. "петух"): кур - курица, (ср. тигр - тигрица). Для множественного числа как общего наименования *вида* (в отличие от ссылки на конкретных куриц - "те /две/ курицы" и т. п.) признак рода не нужен, поэтому оно могло быть образовано от исходного корня.